# Jooq nested select

Tags: java, sql, jooq

First time jooq user here.  I need to convert regular SQL statement with nested select below into jooq.  Any idea if I am on the right path?  I appreciate any help.

```java
//select * 
//from profile 
//where (profile_id, effective_date) in (
//                select profile_id, max(effective_date) as date 
//                from profile 
//                group by profile_id
//                )
```

This is what I have but not sure if even correct:

```java
Result<Record> profiles = dsl_
.select(PROFILE.fields())
.from(PROFILE)
.where(PROFILE.PROFILE_ID, PROFILE.EFFECTIVE_DATE) in (create
    .select(PROFILE.PROFILE_ID, max(PROFILE.EFFECTIVE_DATE) as date
    .from(PROFILE)
    .groupBy(PROFILE.PROFILE_ID)))
    .fetch();
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the [`DSL.row()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) constructor, in order to construct a [row value expression predicate](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/).

Here's how to do that with jOOQ:

```java
// Assuming this:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

// Write
Result<Record> profiles = dsl_
.select(PROFILE.fields())
.from(PROFILE)
.where(row(PROFILE.PROFILE_ID, PROFILE.EFFECTIVE_DATE).in(
     select(PROFILE.PROFILE_ID, max(PROFILE.EFFECTIVE_DATE).as("date"))
    .from(PROFILE)
    .groupBy(PROFILE.PROFILE_ID)
))
.fetch();
```

Comment: I get "ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE" when I try to do something similar to the above (using postgres)

Comment: @RussJackson: Mind asking a new question with details? I'll be happy to answer